# I got error "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero" because modulo make number small

Tags: python, modulo

I have a problem with my code, in the code below the purpose is to change the value in the index of range 4 to n+1. by the flow just put answer[index] = round((answer[i-1]**2)/answer[index-2]) and I need to modulo with 10^9+7 every step but I got error because when modulo I got answer[index-1] < answer[index-2] that why the value smaller till reach 0. Do you have any way to prevent from 0 and the answer still correct? Here is my code below
It starts error when n>1000

```
mod = 10**9+7
n = int(input())
answer = [0]*(n+1)
answer[2] = 8
answer[3] = 22
for index in range(4,n+1,1):
    d = answer[index-1]/answer[index-2]
    ans = round(d*answer[index-1])
    answer[index]=ans%mod
if n == 1:
    print(3)
else:
    print(answer[n]%mod)
```

Comment: I don't know what the code should be doing but it does not raise an error if I try to run it. Please ask a concise *question*.

Comment: No error when running. Please specify expected output and actual output.

Comment: What value of `n` is this error raised for?

Comment: I don't see you using `mod` anywhere.

Comment: It starts error when n > 800

Comment: For me, it blew up with a ZeroDivisionError when index was 224, trying to calculate 0/0.  The numbers get bigger and bigger until index 219 where the modulo operation kicks in and the numbers quickly go to zero.  What is the desired behavior?